# Train Test Split

Tags: julia

I'm doing a Gaussian Process Simulation. I have x and y. I want to divide 85% of them in training and 15% in testing and then model fitting them to predict. How should I write the code? I know in Python the function I use is train_test_split().

```
    x=rand(100)
    dis = [abs(i-j) for i in x, j in x] 
    exp(-dis)
    σ2= 1
    g = 1
    l = Matrix(I,100,100)
    μ = zeros(100)
    Σ = (σ2*exp(-dis/g))+0.1l
    y = MvNormal(μ,Σ)
    Y = rand(y,100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `partition` function from MLJ:

```
using MLJ
MLJ.partition((x, Y), 0.85, multi=true)
```

Here is its documentation https://alan-turing-institute.github.io/MLJ.jl/dev/preparing_data/#Splitting-data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also I'm struggling with the model fitting part. I had an error when I use `fit!()`:                                                                                                                       `julia> fit!(Xtrain,ytrain)ERROR: MethodError: no method matching fit!(::Vector{Float64}, ::Matrix{Float64})
Stacktrace:`

Comment: What model do you want to fit and from what package?

Comment: Gaussian Process Model Fitting

Comment: But what package do you use?

Comment: GaussianProcesses Package? I tried `GP(Xtrain,ytrain,μ,Σ,logNoise=-2.0)`But it doesn't work.

Comment: The way you should use this package in your use case is explained in this notebook https://github.com/STOR-i/GaussianProcesses.jl/blob/master/notebooks/Regression.ipynb.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TrainTestSplit` from package `Lathe`

```
using Lathe.preprocess: TrainTestSplit
traindf, testdf = TrainTestSplit(df,.85);
```

Check this link for more: https://github.com/emmettgb/Lathe-Books/tree/main/preprocess

Comment: Lathe seems to be extremely stale, and installing it causes a vast number of other packages to be reverted to very old versions. If this is true, I'd not recommend it

Answer (score 0):

Or, still use [`partition`](https://sylvaticus.github.io/BetaML.jl/dev/Utils.html#BetaML.Api.partition-Union%7BTuple%7BT%7D,%20Tuple%7BAbstractVector%7BT%7D,%20AbstractVector%7BFloat64%7D%7D%7D%20where%20T%3C:AbstractArray) from BetaML:

```
using BetaML
((xtrain,xtest),(ytrain,ytest)) = partition([x,y],[0.85,0.15])
```

This generalise to n arrays (e.g. train/val/test) and you can also choose the dimension to where to partition and if randomise or not the partition.